# VB6 ADO Recordset Limit

Tags: vb6, ado, recordset

Please don't laugh because I'm asking a VB6 question? I have to do some maintenance work. Does anyone know what the maximum number of rows can be returned to a VB6 ADO Recordset? If there is a limit, is there a preferred method for getting around it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no limit (see link for documentation), but you can provide one if you want. There should be a [MaxRecords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property that you can set. You have to set it before you open the recordset.

Comment: I don't think this is Connection related, just set it before opening the Recordset.

Comment: Thanks for the response vcsjones. Is there a max amount of memory used by it?

Comment: @StoneFX - "Maximum Memory" is a funny subject, but a process is limited to just a hair under 2GB. As far as I know, there is no way to limit the amount of memory used by a recordset, but limiting the MaxRecords will have a similar result.

Answer (score 1):

The [RecordCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property is a (signed) Long (as is the MaxRecords) so it won't be able to hold more than 2,147,483,647 rows

Comment: Assuming Win32 long; shouldn't it be 2,147,483,647 (2^31 - 1) since it is signed?

Comment: @vcsjones Win32 long is assumed as the question is tagged vb6, but you are correct it is signed - I will edit my answer.